# Unitary multiplication operator

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I came across this exercise from book 'Linear Operator Theory
in Engineering
and Science'. I want to show that function multiplication is unitary if and only if the absolute value of the function is 1 a.e.. The problem is below:
$$
\begin{array}{l}{\text { Let I }=[a, b] \text { be a bounded interval and define } F: L_{2}(I) \rightarrow L_{2}(I)} \\ {\text { by }(F x)(t)=f(t) x(t), \text { where } f \in L_{\infty}(I) . \text {how toshow that } F \text { is a unitary mapping if and only if }|f(t)|=1 \text { almost }} \\ {\text { everywhere? }}\end{array}
$$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Obviously $F$ is a bounded (because $f\in L_\infty(I)$) linear operator so how useful intermediate steps might be the following: (1) How does the inner product on $L_2(I)$ look like? (2) Can one say something about the adjoint operator $F^*$ of $F$? (3) What does it mean for $F$ to be unitary?

Comment: Just a simple question, is 'almost everywhere' part trivial? Why we need that? I can't see it has anything to do with the null set.

Comment: As you probably found out yourself, the condition for unitarity of $F$ reads $|f(t)|^2 x(t)=x(t)$ for all $t\in I$ and all $x(t)\in L^2(I)$. But two functions *by definition of* $L^2(I)$ are the same if they coincide almost everywhere, i.e. "they cannot be distinguished via the Lebesgue measure". So if $|f(t)|^2=1$ everywhere *aside from* a set of measure zero then $F$ is still unitary because "you cannot tell it apart from a unitary operator".

Comment: (2/2) I hope this clears up things (if it does not, feel free to ask further)! Also if you believe you solved the problem now, you may consider giving an answer below yourself